# I'm working with JavaScript (DOM), and I can't console log my innerHTML directly in my browser's console

Tags: javascript, dom

here is my problem
[image: here is my problem]

what it should be
[image: what it should be]

```js
const span = document.querySelector("span")
console.log(span.parentNode);
console.log(span.parentElement);
console.log(span.parentNode.parentNode);
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- beforebegin -->
  <h3>
    <!-- afterbegin -->
    <span class="span">khải lê</span>
    <span class="span2">kai</span>
    <!-- beforeend -->
  </h3>
  <!-- afterend -->
  <script src="JS/DOM/TRAVERSING.JS"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: where do you log the innerHTML? you log elements and now the browser displays the element in the console differs.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by just logging the `innerHTML` property.
Like:

```js
const span = document.querySelector("span");
console.log(span.innerHTML);
console.log(span.parentElement.innerHTML);
console.log(span.parentNode.innerHTML);
```

Comment: thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can:

```js
const span = document.querySelector("span")
console.log(span.parentNode.innerHTML);
console.log(span.parentElement.innerHTML);
console.log(span.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML);
```

```html
<body>
  <!-- beforebegin -->
  <h3>
    <!-- afterbegin -->
    <span class="span">khải lê</span>
    <span class="span2">kai</span>
    <!-- beforeend -->
  </h3>
  <!-- afterend -->
  <script src="JS/DOM/TRAVERSING.JS"></script>
</body>
```